# How to build a multi-dimentional json native query for Druid?

Tags: postman, druid

I have data with multiple dimensions, stored in the Druid cluster. for example, Data of movies and the revenue they earned from each country where they were screened.
I'm trying to build a query that the answer to be returned will be a table of all the movies, the total revenue of each of them, and the revenue for each country.

I succeeded to do it in Turnilo - it generated for me the following Druid query -

```
[


[
    {
      "queryType": "timeseries",
      "dataSource": "movies_source",
      "intervals": "2021-11-18T00:01Z/2021-11-21T00:01Z",
      "granularity": "all",
      "aggregations": [
        {
          "name": "__VALUE__",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "revenue"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "queryType": "topN",
      "dataSource": "movies_source",
      "intervals": "2021-11-18T00:01Z/2021-11-21T00:01Z",
      "granularity": "all",
      "dimension": {
        "type": "default",
        "dimension": "movie_id",
        "outputName": "movie_id"
      },
      "aggregations": [
        {
          "name": "revenue",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "revenue"
        }
      ],
      "metric": "revenue",
      "threshold": 50
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "queryType": "topN",
      "dataSource": "movies_source",
      "intervals": "2021-11-18T00:01Z/2021-11-21T00:01Z",
      "granularity": "all",
      "filter": {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "movie_id",
        "value": "some_movie_id"
      },
      "dimension": {
        "type": "default",
        "dimension": "country",
        "outputName": "country"
      },
      "aggregations": [
        {
          "name": "revenue",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "revenue"
        }
      ],
      "metric": "revenue",
      "threshold": 5
    }
  ]
]
```

But it doesn't work when I'm trying to use it as a body for a Postman query - I got

```
{
    "error": "Unknown exception",
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token (START_ARRAY), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of org.apache.druid.query.Query)\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 2, column: 3]",
    "errorClass": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException",
    "host": null
}
```

How should I build the corresponding query so that it works with Postman?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Turnilo but have you tried using the Druid Console to write SQL and convert to Native request with the "Explain SQL query" option under the "Run/..." menu?

Your native queries seem to be doing a Top N instead of listing all movies, so I think the SQL might be something like:

```
SELECT movie_id, country_id, SUM(revenue) total_revenue
FROM movies_source
WHERE __time BETWEEN '2021-11-18 00:01:00' AND '2021-11-21 00:01:00'
GROUP BY movie_id, country_id
ORDER BY total_revenue DESC
LIMIT 50
```

I don't have the data source to test, but tested with sample wikipedia data with similar query structure:

```
SELECT namespace, cityName, sum(sum_added) total
FROM "wikipedia" r 
WHERE cityName IS NOT NULL
 AND __time BETWEEN '2015-09-12 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-15 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY namespace, cityName
ORDER BY total DESC
limit 50
```

which results in the following Native query:

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": {
    "type": "table",
    "name": "wikipedia"
  },
  "intervals": {
    "type": "intervals",
    "intervals": [
      "2015-09-12T00:00:00.000Z/2015-09-15T00:00:00.001Z"
    ]
  },
  "virtualColumns": [],
  "filter": {
    "type": "not",
    "field": {
      "type": "selector",
      "dimension": "cityName",
      "value": null,
      "extractionFn": null
    }
  },
  "granularity": {
    "type": "all"
  },
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "dimension": "namespace",
      "outputName": "d0",
      "outputType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "type": "default",
      "dimension": "cityName",
      "outputName": "d1",
      "outputType": "STRING"
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type": "longSum",
      "name": "a0",
      "fieldName": "sum_added",
      "expression": null
    }
  ],
  "postAggregations": [],
  "having": null,
  "limitSpec": {
    "type": "default",
    "columns": [
      {
        "dimension": "a0",
        "direction": "descending",
        "dimensionOrder": {
          "type": "numeric"
        }
      }
    ],
    "limit": 50
  },
  "context": {
    "populateCache": false,
    "sqlOuterLimit": 101,
    "sqlQueryId": "cd5aabed-5e08-49b7-af63-fe82c125d3ee",
    "useApproximateCountDistinct": false,
    "useApproximateTopN": false,
    "useCache": false
  },
  "descending": false
}
```